# ATV doesn't see my Home Sharing

Tags: itunes, appletv, home-sharing

I have my MP6,1 connected via Ether to my Time Capsule, and my ATV connected via Ether to the same TC. Everything seems to be working, but my ATV cannot see my Home Sharing movies.

I have both the ATV and MP with HS turned on, and connected to the same iCloud account. The ATV simply doesn't see my iTunes.

I can, however, use screen casting from my MP to the ATV just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it just the HS movies, or all content from iTunes.  If it's just movies, they might not be in an ATV compatible format (more limited than iTunes' formats).  Can you see *anything* in the "Computers" section of the ATV, like music?

Comment: Nothing at all shows up in the Computers section. Good thought, I see where you're going here.

Comment: Hmmm, how about if you create a new acct on the MP, log in as that new user, open iTunes, add a single song or something, and turn on HS under that iTunes acct.  Can the ATV see that?  You can have multiple iTunes on the same network all using the same HS acct, and the ATV will let you pick between them (when it's working).  There could be something "corrupt" in your iTunes library, and creating a fresh library might give you a clue.